# Laravel 4 db:seed receiving ErrorExecption

Tags: php, macos, laravel-4

For some reason I am getting an [ErrorException] Trying to get property of non-object... when I run php artisan db:seed. It was working before but then I started to get this error out of no where. I ran composer update, migrate:refresh and nothing appears to work. This is what my code looks like right now.

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
 class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Eloquent::unguard();
        $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
        $this->call('RolesTableSeeder');
    }

}

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run() {

        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            $user = User::create([
                'username' => $faker->firstName,
                'email' => $faker->email,
                'password' => 1234,
                'gender' => rand(0, 1) ? 'male' : 'female',
                'birthday_year' => $faker->year,
                'birthday_month' => $faker->dayOfMonth,
                'birthday_day' => $faker->month,
                'country' => $faker->stateAbbr,
                'city' => $faker->city,
                'zip' => $faker->postcode
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also in my user table I have the $fillable property set.

Comment: Does it tell you what line the error is occuring? Just start commenting out some of your code until your work out exactly which line is triggering the error

Comment: yes, I started to do that and I may have a bug in a conditional inside my User model dealing with the newQuery function.